# Tryng to enable the passhtru of one Nvidia gpu to a Bhyve Linux vm on FreeBSD 14.0

Tags: freebsd, virtual-machine, nvidia, gpu-passthrough, bhyve

For some years it worked,but now,maybe due to the recent changes added on the FreeBSD 13 and 14 code,it does not work anymore : I'm talking about the ability to passthru one Nvidia GpU from the host os (FreeBSD 14.0 in this case) to any Linux vm. The same procedure that worked until "yesterday" it does not work anymore (for me).

The developer does not reply to my message anymore. I would like to be sure that is true that it is bugged,as it seems,and not that I'm making some mistake. So,I will explain what I do to enable this functionality. I hope that someone wants to also try or that he tries a different procedure that works. The most important thing is that we will be able to enable the function.

So,time ago the developer gave me 3 scripts to run in sequence. They are the following :

a) setup_git_140.sh

```
git clone https://github.com/beckhoff/freebsd-src /usr/corvin-src-140
```

b) build_branch_140.sh

```bash
    #!/bin/sh
    
    usage() {
        cat >&2 << EOF
    Usage: ${0} <branch> [<build_options>]
        Checkouts to <branch> and builds it with 
    <build_options> (see build.sh for more information).
    EOF
        exit 1
    }
    
    set -e
    set -u
    
    readonly script_path="$(cd "$(dirname "${0}")" && pwd)"
    readonly branch="${1?Missing <branch>$(usage)}"
    shift
    echo $branch
    
    cd /usr/corvin-src-140
    git fetch --all --prune
    git checkout -f "${branch}"
    
    ${script_path}/build_140.sh "$@"
```

c) build_build_140.sh

```bash
    #!/bin/sh
    
    usage() {
        cat >&2 << EOF
    Usage: ${0} [--no-bhf] [--reboot] [--verbose] [--without-
    kernel]
        Builds bhyve
    EOF
        exit 1
    }
    
    build_module() {
        local _path
        _path="${1}"
    
        # change to module path
        cd "${_path}"
    
        # clean module
        if test "${clean}" = "true"; then
            make clean > "${cmd_redirect}" 2>&1
        fi
    
        # build module
        make > "${cmd_redirect}" 2>&1
    
        # install module
        make install > "${cmd_redirect}"
    }
    
    build() {
        build_module "${src_dir}/include"
        build_module "${src_dir}/lib/libvmmapi"
        build_module "${src_dir}/sys/modules/vmm"
    
        # build kernel
        if test "${with_kernel}" = "true"; then
            cd "${src_dir}"
            local kern_opts
            kern_opts="-j$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)"
            if test "${with_bhf}" = "true"; then
                kern_opts="${kern_opts} 
    KERNCONF=BHF"
            fi
            if ! test "${clean}" = "true"; then
                kern_opts="${kern_opts} 
    NO_CLEAN=YES"
            fi
            make kernel ${kern_opts} > "${cmd_redirect}" 2>&1
        fi
    
        build_module "${src_dir}/usr.sbin/bhyve"
        build_module "${src_dir}/usr.sbin/bhyvectl"
        build_module "${src_dir}/usr.sbin/bhyveload"
    
        if test "${with_reboot}" = "true"; then
            reboot
        fi
    }
    
    set -e
    set -u
    
    while test $# -gt 0; do
        case "${1-}" in
            --clean)
                clean="true"
                shift
                ;;
            --reboot)
                with_reboot="true"
                shift
                ;;
            --src-dir=*)
                src_dir="${1#*=}"
                shift
                ;;
            --verbose)
                cmd_redirect="/dev/stdout"
                shift
                ;;
            --without-bhf)
                with_bhf="false"
                shift
                ;;
            --without-kernel)
                with_kernel="false"
                shift
                ;;
            *)
                usage
                ;;
        esac
    done
    
    readonly clean="${clean-"false"}"
    readonly cmd_redirect="${cmd_redirect-"/dev/null"}"
    readonly src_dir="${src_dir-"/usr/corvin-src-140"}"
    echo $src_dir
    readonly with_bhf="${with_bhf-"true"}"
    readonly with_kernel="${with_kernel-"true"}"
    readonly with_reboot="${with_reboot-"false"}"
    
    build
```

Here we go. This is what I do to start the compilation that should produce the working bhyve system files that will give to use the passthru of one nvidia gpu on FreeBSD 14.0 :

```
a) ./setup_git_140.sh

b) ./build_branch_140.sh origin/phab/corvink/14.0/nvidia-wip --without-bhf --verbose
```

ok. It compiled the code without giving errors,until a certain point,when it happens what you see below. I want to understand if the code is bugged. Please help me :

```
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1174:21: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ctx'
                passthru_cfgwrite(ctx, vcpu, pi, offset - 
0x88000, size, value);
                                  ^
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1174:26: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'vcpu'
                passthru_cfgwrite(ctx, vcpu, pi, offset - 
0x88000, size, value);
                                       ^
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1209:20: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ctx'
                passthru_cfgread(ctx, vcpu, pi, offset - 
0x88000, size, (uint32_t *)&val);
                                 ^
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1209:25: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'vcpu'
                passthru_cfgread(ctx, vcpu, pi, offset - 
0x88000, size, (uint32_t *)&val);
                                      ^
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1302:29: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ctx'
                        if (vm_unmap_pptdev_mmio(ctx, sc-
>psc_sel.pc_bus,
                                                 ^
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1309:27: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ctx'
                        if (vm_map_pptdev_mmio(ctx, sc-
>psc_sel.pc_bus,
                                               ^
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1327:29: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ctx'
                        if (vm_unmap_pptdev_mmio(ctx, sc-
>psc_sel.pc_bus,
                                                 ^
/usr/corvin-src-140/usr.sbin/bhyve/pci_passthru.c:1334:27: 
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ctx'
                        if (vm_map_pptdev_mmio(ctx, sc-
>psc_sel.pc_bus,
                                               ^
8 errors generated.
*** Error code 1
```

The passthru of one nvidia card inside a linux vm WILL NOT work if you don't do what I have explained. The FreeBSD wiki does not talk about the nvidia gpu,but only about network interfaces. If you want to help me,if you have one nvidia card, if you want to pass it through inside a Linux VM,you SHOULD repeat the steps that I have explained. And tell me if you are able to compile the code successfully.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to update `setup_git_140.sh` to pull by TAG and not the entire repo/main, and you'd see the mistake.  [Release Tags](https://github.com/Beckhoff/freebsd-src/tags).  As you can see there is no 14.0.0 tag, which means you need to see if it builds on 13, as that is the last available tag.  Unfortunately, it looks like the headers were altered in version 14.  I believe the identifiers are defined in the Kernel Header Files.  They were either removed or renamed, which is what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

### Checkout by TAG

To checkout a tag:

1. First, lets gather all the tags: `git fetch --all --tags`
2. After finding the available tags: `git checkout tags/<tag> -b <branch>`

The TAG and the BRANCH NAME should relatively match.

You only need to either update the Fetch commands, or tell the developer to harvest the tags in the script he gave you, and then print and fetch either the one you select or the most recent.

### Second Method

1. Visit the [Tags Page](https://github.com/Beckhoff/freebsd-src/tags).
2. As you can see there is no Tag for 14 yet, but you can download the source tarball and extract it to your `/usr/corvon/src` location when it's ready.

Using the method you were given will work when the source is ready to build.  WIP indicates *Work In Progress*.  Treat this as a daily/nightly build that won't always build.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand if it will work or not. And if it can work,how ? Can you post here the commands that I should Issue ? sorry I'm not experienced with this kind of stuff.

Comment: I posted the commands above

Comment: # git clone https://github.com/beckhoff/freebsd-src /usr/corvin-src ; # cd /usr/corvin-src ; # git fetch --all --tags = NO OUTPUT.

Comment: maybe this ? ---> https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WWkxDnnVQB/

Comment: Instead,listing branches you will see what I need : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XGZD9xgW4R/ ; I mean this : "origin/phab/corvink/14.0/nvidia-wip"

Comment: WIP indicates Work In Progress, meaning it's not guaranteed to build (yet).  You need to report the failure back to the repository.  Chances are they already know.  As I said earlier, I suspect a header change.  Please learn git.  `git fetch --all --tags` will work but you CANNOT `prune` it before hand.  See 2nd Method.

Comment: Do you mean to grab this TARBALL ? --> https://github.com/Beckhoff/freebsd-src/archive/refs/heads/phab/corvink/14.0/nvidia-wip.zip ; can you also explain how to compile this code ? very very thanks.

Comment: It does not work even with 13.1 : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/gWFmm8fMZR/